# How to return all columns from 1st table and only 1 column from 2nd table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a first table called "purchases"

```
news_series, transaction_id, owner_id, amount
```

I have another table called "Events"

```
news_name, news_id, series_id, news_description
```

The issue that I'm running into is that if I do

```
purchases.news_series joins to events.series_id
```

The issues is that there can be multiple events with the series id....

I need to join just one to get the ***news_name*** from the joined table so the base select is

```
Select * from purchases where owner_id=29

140, asldkfj_sdfx34, 29, 40
```

then I add the joined table

```
Select * 
from purchases 
LEFT JOIN events on purchases.news_series=events.series_id 
where owner_id=29

140, asldkfj_sdfx34, 29, 40,"THIS EVENT", 606, 140, "MY FIRST EVENT"
140, asldkfj_sdfx34, 29, 40,"THIS EVENT", 607, 140, "MY FIRST EVENT"
```

and I end up with a few rows returned...I just need one to capture the new_name from the events table.

Comment: added data returned

Comment: @BostonMaxOSX Thank you for adding the extra information to help resolve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just need one to capture the news_name from the events table.

This is what I would do:

PURCHASES TABLE:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------+--------+
| news_series | transaction_id | owner_id | amount |
+-------------+----------------+----------+--------+
| 140         | asldkfj_sdfx34 | 29       | 40     |
+-------------+----------------+----------+--------+
```

EVENTS TABLE:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
| news_name  | news_id | series_id | news_description |
+------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
| THIS EVENT | 606     | 140       | MY FIRST EVENT   |
+------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
| THIS EVENT | 607     | 140       | MY FIRST EVENT   |
+------------+---------+-----------+------------------+
```

---

`SELECT DISTINCT` just the one column you want from the joined table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, e.news_name
FROM Purchases p
LEFT JOIN Events e ON p.news_series = e.series_id
WHERE p.owner_id = 29
```

[image]

---

If you do not `SELECT DISTINCT`, this is why you are getting two rows.

[image]

---

Test:

```
;WITH Purchases (news_series, transaction_id, owner_id, amount) AS (
    SELECT '140','asldkfj_sdfx34','29','40'
), Events (news_name,news_id,series_id,news_description) AS (
    SELECT 'THIS EVENT','606','140','MY FIRST EVENT' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'THIS EVENT','607','140','MY FIRST EVENT' )

SELECT DISTINCT p.*, e.news_name
FROM Purchases p
LEFT JOIN Events e ON p.news_series = e.series_id
WHERE p.owner_id = 29
```

Comment: You are addind data not in the example... 1 purchase row with 2 events row which join to it..but I only need the 1 purchase row with the news_name added..you have added many rows...

Comment: There was a perfect example in the original post....with the SQL and the results..you deleted the second row of respone on the join because you didn't realize that the news_id was different...606 and 607

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest:

```
Select p.*,
       (select e.news_name
        from events e
        where p.news_series = e.series_id 
        limit 1
       )
from purchases  p
where owner_id = 29;
```

This is guaranteed to return one row per purchase.

Comment: I like this solution as well but I can only check one

Comment: @BostonMacOSX . . . Just for the record, I think this one is much more efficient.